# Does the game scale with your progress?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I am under the impression that the game gives you harder enemies the more you advance.

At the beginning, I would get mostly red bokoblins, with 1 blue bokoblin per camp, but now, it's mostly blue/black bokoblins, with 1 silver bokoblin per camp. And that is around the 4 main cities, to which you can go at any time of the game, so I guess they should be around the same camp difficulty?

Is it only an impression, or does the game scale up the enemies the farther you progress?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enemies are not scaled to your game progress. Rather, enemies are scaled to how many enemies you have killed. The more Bokoblins, Moblins, Lynels, etc. that you kill, the more likely you are to encounter blue, black, and silver variants.

Comment: Any source, or is it personnal experience?

Comment: I had assumed the number of completed Devine Beasts influenced the ranks of the enemies that appear. The random appearance of Yiga Clan members is triggered by a direct progress event.

Comment: @Fredy31 as I was going to answer this as well, it appears that the guide indicates this behavior. Though I cannot find the guide online, I saw this tidbit referenced.

Comment: @Gwellin I can confirm, at least anecdotally, it's not tied to Divine Beast completion. I lagged a bit on story completion and was running into a lot of Silver mobs before even starting my second.