# Where can I find a ton of Silver enemies?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Where can I find Silver enemies like Silver Bokoblins and any other Silver enemy abundantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you complete the game once, all but three Lynels on the world map will become Silver Lynels. (The three remaining Lynels are one of each colour (Red, Blue and White) to allow you to get the pictures).

A lot of enemies within Hyrule Castle are silver tier. A Silver Moblin and 2 Silver Lizalfos can be found in the Training Room. More silver Moblins can be found throughout the castle.

Comment: The more you kill, the more ennemies will be silver. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304549/does-the-game-scale-with-your-progress So just keep on killing.

Comment: @SGR This is not true. I watched the stream of a friend of mine who encountered several Silver Lynels with only two Devine Beasts defeated. Perhaps after beating the game the chance of discovering Silver enemies is maxed out regardless of earlier actions.

Comment: @Gwellin That doesn't contradict the answer though. It's possible that completing the game causes all (but the 3) Lynels to become silver, but as Fredy31 mentioned, just killing enemies may also cause this earlier.

Answer (score -6):

Go on master mode. There's TONS of silver enemies there (AND golden enemies)

Comment: 1) This is assuming that everybody has Master Mode and 2) "There's tons" isn't very descriptive on exactly where

Comment: @Wondercricket Completely agree. Of course, to be fair, the OP did actually ask where to find "a ton of Silver enemies".

Comment: Assuming you have Master Mode, you can find silver enemies pretty much almost everywhere in Hyrule Castle (i.e., Lockup, Docks, Library, Guard's Chamber, etc) and a lot of them in the Coliseum Ruins (once you have completed all 4 divine beasts, there will be 3 Silver Lizalfos, 3 Silver Bokoblins, and 3 Silver Moblins there). Also, right under the Eldin Great Skeleton, there's a camp of silver/golden enemies there. Just beneath Tabantha tower there's also of camp of the same sorts. Also, to the east of the desert's Great Fairy, there's a camp of Silver Bokoblins there.

Comment: Just to add on, if you're on normal mode, once you got far enough in the game you'll start to see silver lynels. As for silver bokoblins, you can find one near the shrine in Mount Hylia on Great Plateau, another one just southeast of Foothill Stable. Silver Lizalfos, there's a camp of lizalfos just east of Gerudo Town, and the Lanaryu Gate has 4 silver lizalfos there. Silver moblins, just below the Tabantha Tower, some on the route to Highland Stable, and some near the Deplian Badlands. Those are just a few locations to spot the silver ones.